# What does "go on an acquisition tear" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean the company will be torn apart after the acquisition?

Johnston says the SodaStream deal should not be seen as a sign that the company is about to go on an acquisition tear.

Source:http://fortune.com/2018/08/20/pepsico-sodastream-acquisition/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, *go on an acquisition tear* is slang for "be busy with a lot of acquisitions."

From the Collins definition of [**on a tear**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/on-a-tear):

> showing a sudden burst of energy

And from [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+a+tear):

> 1. Very active, often suddenly. *A: "Why is mom cleaning every room in the house?" B: "Oh, she's been on a tear ever since she saw a mouse in the basement this morning." Well, your grandmother is on an earlier flight, so I've been on a tear trying to get everything ready for her arrival.*

---

So, to rephrase the sentence:

> Johnston says the SodaStream deal should not be seen as a sign that the company is about to be busy with a lot of acquisitions.

Or, more simply:

> Johnston says the SodaStream deal should not be seen as a sign that the company is going to start making a lot of acquisitions.